# Draw curves and polygons in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a lot confusing in how to draw some pictures using tikz. 
The firts one is a equilateral (not regular) polygon, like this:

[image]

And some smooth curves like this:

[image]

If you can help me, I don't have so much experience in tikz.

Comment: Welcome! This isn't really a fair question for this site: just a do-it-for-me (or, actually, twice-do-it-for-me). Look at some examples, read the tutorials in the manual and ask about specific problems if you get stuck. You may get lucky and find a procrastinator to do everything for you, but you'll more probably get help if you post code for a minimal document people can start from, showing what you've got and where you're stuck. If you don't want to do that, I recommend asking for a picture involving a duck to maximise your chances of getting somebody to do the lot for you.

Comment: `hobby` for the curves. An equilateral triangle is a regular triangle. So what is a non-regular equilateral polygon?

Comment: @cfr A polygon whose sides are all the same length but whose interior angles are not the same size.

Comment: I just want some tips, not the entire code. But thanks for the explanation. Tomorrow I'll put some code I've been done. 
About the polygons, i'm talking about equilateral polygons wich have more then three sides, without necessarely have the same angles.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oh. I thought the '(not regular)' was meant to explain the 'equilateral', which I couldn't make sense of. 'non-regular equilateral' is meant, it seems.

Comment: @cfr Probably because you had in mind the triangle, which if is equilateral is necessarily also regular :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Well, I also thought about an equilateral polygon and couldn't see why it shouldn't also be regular. But you're right, I started with the triangle.